# a href links are not working inside of a accordion, it seems Javascript overwrites click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

a href links are not working inside of a accordion when click the a href links. It seems that the JS function of accordion overwrites the a href links. Now clicking the link, instead of opening another page, it expands in and out(this is the function the JS for), which is the original function of the JS. What I want to do is keeping the accordion function, and make the a href links work.  Here is the example code: http://jsfiddle.net/mrPWa/

```
    <script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript">


$(function() { 
height = $(window).height();
 $('.Accord').css({height: height});

    $('.Accord').toggle(function() {
   $('.Accord').animate({width: "20%"}, 500 );
      $(this).removeClass('deSelect');
         $(this).animate({ width: "40%"}, {duration: 500, queue: false});
            $('.deSelect').animate({width: "15%"}, {duration: 500, queue: false});
               $(this).addClass('deSelect');

  }, function() {   
       $('.deSelect').animate({width: "20%"}, 500);



  });
 });
```

The a href links are here.

```
   <body>

      <div id="Sponsorships_index">

<div id="accordionWrapper">

    <ol>
        <li id="snow" class="Accord deSelect">
        <a href="http://www.apple.com/"> 
        <h1>Apple link is not working!!!!!</h1></a>

        </li>

        <li id="street" class="Accord deSelect">
              <a href="http://www.apple.com/"> 
        <h1>Apple link is not working!!!!!</h1></a>
        </li>

        <li id="water" class="Accord deSelect">

        </li>

        <li id="dirt" class="Accord deSelect">

        </li>

        <li id="sound" class="Accord deSelect">

        </li>
    </ol>
</div>​

  </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: nothing in code shown should do anything to links. Create a demo that replicates issue in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Sorry, I should have the code cleaned up more. Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/mrPWa/

Comment: It is not. It's two different projects, they might look similar.

Comment: I learned, but it doesn't seem that I can use that to help this issue. event.preventDefault() is like this, but event.preventDefault() is prevent default click function, that's not what i want. I want to have the original function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to the end of your toggle function

```
.on('click', 'a', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); })
```

to prevent the event from bubbling up.

so you end up with

```
$('.Accord').toggle(function() {
    $('.Accord').animate({ width: "20%" }, 500)
    $(this).removeClass('deSelect')
    $(this).animate({ width: "40%" }, { duration: 500, queue: false })
    $('.deSelect').animate({ width: "15%" }, { duration: 500, queue: false })
    $(this).addClass('deSelect')
}, function () {
    $('a').click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); })
    $('.deSelect').animate({ width: "20%" }, 500)
}).on('click', 'a', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); })
```

test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/sSG2f/

Comment: Thanks so much. That's what I am looking for: event.stopPropagation();  I will remember that. By the way, by any chance, do you know why the last accordion (blue accordion) always shift down (disappear) when any of the accordion gets unexpanded? I found out this issue is varied, it sometimes is fine, but sometimes is not. Like now I am testing it at Chrome, it is fine. But if I use Firefox to text it, the problem comes again.

Comment: Just had a similar issue and this solved it.  Thanks a lot @RASG