# Accordion not opening the links

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Here's a html and js, which I am using for accordion. Issue is when I click on links its not opening. But when I center click on links its opening correctly in new tab.

I also have to used these links in table format, so I can show media releases yearwise.

Here's the accordion html if it's helpful:

```
<div class="container">
          <h1>Simple Flat UI CSS Accordion</h1>
          <div class="accordion">
            <dl>
              <dt><a class="accordionTitle accordionTitleActive" href="#">Test Simple Flat UI CSS Accordion 1</a></dt>
              <dd class="accordionItem">
                <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>22 September 2022</td>
            <td><a href="www.google.com">Google</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>29 August 2022</td>
           <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a></td>
        </tr>
 
       
    </tbody>
</table>
              </dd>
              <dt><a href="#" class="accordionTitle">Test Simple Flat UI CSS Accordion 2</a></dt>
              <dd class="accordionItem accordionItemCollapsed">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eu interdum diam. Donec interdum porttitor risus non bibendum. Maecenas sollicitudin eros in quam imperdiet placerat. Cras justo purus, rhoncus nec lobortis ut, iaculis vel ipsum. Donec dignissim arcu nec elit faucibus condimentum. Donec facilisis consectetur enim sit amet varius. Pellentesque justo dui, sodales quis luctus a, iaculis eget mauris. </p>
              </dd>
             
            </dl>
          </div>
</div>
```

JS used

```
( function( window ) {
'use strict';
function classReg( className ) {
return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}
var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
return elem.classList.contains( c );
};
addClass = function( elem, c ) {
elem.classList.add( c );
};
removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
elem.classList.remove( c );
};
}
else {
hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
};
addClass = function( elem, c ) {
if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
}
};
removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
};
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
fn( elem, c );
}
var classie = {
hasClass: hasClass,
addClass: addClass,
removeClass: removeClass,
toggleClass: toggleClass,
has: hasClass,
add: addClass,
remove: removeClass,
toggle: toggleClass
};
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
define( classie );
} else {
window.classie = classie;
}
})( window );
var $ = function(selector){
return document.querySelector(selector);
}
var accordion = $('.accordion');
accordion.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "A") {
var classes = e.target.className.split(" ");
if(classes) {
for(var x = 0; x \< classes.length; x++) {
if(classes\[x\] == "accordionTitle") {
var title = e.target;
var content = e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
classie.toggle(title, 'accordionTitleActive');
if(classie.has(content, 'accordionItemCollapsed')) {
if(classie.has(content, 'animateOut')){
classie.remove(content, 'animateOut');
}
classie.add(content, 'animateIn');
}else{
classie.remove(content, 'animateIn');
classie.add(content, 'animateOut');
}
classie.toggle(content, 'accordionItemCollapsed');  
}
}
}  
}
});
```

I tried adding this line but then hyperlinks are working and accordions are not working.

```
.on('click', 'a', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); })
```

Comment: Original code you can find here: 
https://codepen.io/samsurysites/pen/JjBgrQ

Comment: somehow this solution helps but then hyperlinks are working and accordions are not working.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923109/a-href-links-are-not-working-inside-of-a-accordion-it-seems-javascript-overwrit

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is this one.

```
<span onclick="event.stopPropagation();"> <a href="#"> link title </a> </span>
```